# Total no of occurrence of 1 in monotonic lattice paths from (0,0) to (N,N)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

It's a combinatorial problem which is disturbing me from couple of days now. 
I was going through **Catalan Numbers** [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics)

There is a property of a catalan number that

> Cn is the number of monotonic lattice paths along the edges of a grid with n × n square cells, which do not pass above the diagonal

Lets take example
For N = 3, *the monotonic lattice paths* are
[0 0 0 3], [0 0 1 2], [0 0 2 1], [0 1 0 2], [0 1 1 1].
(Note : The notation used here is the increase in column-height.)

I need to have **count of 1's in all of these paths**. So,
*Total no of 1's = 6.*

How do I approach this problem? I have very less knowledge of combinatorics.

Comment: What notation do you use for those paths? On the linked wiki page they use column height, in which case your notation would give illegal paths.

Comment: I too used column height as notation. Move right and move up. And all these paths never cross the diagonal so how can they be illegal? You can take example given in wiki page. I just used a smaller example

Comment: For example `[0, 0, 2, 1]` goes to height 2 and then back down to height 1.

Comment: @orlp its the increase in height that is used as notation in my case. I'll add that in question too.